# Creating a dialog for a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to use jQuery-UI´s dialog to create a confirmation dialog attached to a link, but it´s not working and the documentation for dialogs at jQuery-UI´s home seems to be lacking.

I want to display a dialog explaining what action will be taken with any extra data the user may need to take the decision and asking for confirmation when a link is clicked, but once the dialog is created it "steals" the text from the link, and leaves nothing in place for the user to click.

Does anyone knows how to do what I´m trying, or at least knows a link for a better documentation for jQuery-UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a sample of the code you're having trouble with? Based on your description, it sounds like you might be creating the dialog incorrectly.

Comment: This is what I´m trying for now: `$(".reagendar").dialog({ 
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   title: "Reagendar",
   buttons: [
    {        text: "Não",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    },
    {
        text: "Sim",
        click: function() { 
                      alert($(this).html());
        }
    } 
   ] 
  }
 );
`

Comment: You need your link to open the dialog to be separate from the code which creates your dialog.

Comment: I suspected as much, but haven´t been able to get it to work. I´m quite new at jQuery. By the way, how do I format my text here? I can´t even hit enter without submiting a comment.

Comment: You need your link to open the dialog to be separate from the code which creates your dialog.

`<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  $('#mydialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});
  $('#mylink').click(function () {
     $('#mydialog').dialog('open');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="mylink">click here</a>
<div id="mydialog" title="my dialog">Nao</div>`

Comment: you can also find a good example here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated click on the view source link below the example

Comment: This should work, except I haven´t found a way to give an ID for each of my dialogs (dinamically created, one for each row in a table), but that may be lack of caffeine. I´m accepting this answer, and working out what´s left. Thank you for the help.